# Get MAC address of device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm writing a Windows Phone 8.1 Application that discovers nearby Bluetooth Low Energy devices.

```
foreach (DeviceInformation device in devices)
{
    BluetoothLEDevice bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
}
```

Everything works fine, but the `bleDevice.BluetoothAddress` property contains a `ulong` type, while I need a string type, formatted like a Mac Address.

Example:

> > **bleDevice.BluetoothAddress:** 254682828386071 (ulong)
> >
> > **Desired Mac Address:** D1:B4:EC:14:29:A8 (string) (that's an example of how I need it, not the actual Mac Address of the device)

Is there a way to convert the long to a Mac Address? Or is there another way to directly discover the Mac Address without conversions? I know there's a tool named `In The HAnd - 32feet` that could help me, but as of now Windows Phone 8.1 is not supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are numerous topics you can find through Google and here on StackOverflow. Anyway, here's one way to do it:

```
ulong input = 254682828386071;
var tempMac = input.ToString("X");
//tempMac is now 'E7A1F7842F17'

var regex = "(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})";
var replace = "$1:$2:$3:$4:$5:$6";
var macAddress = Regex.Replace(tempMac, regex, replace);
//macAddress is now 'E7:A1:F7:84:2F:17'
```

Comment: Thanks for the code!  

While I was waiting, I noticed that the BluetoothLEDevice item also has the property DeviceId that contains (a bit hidden, really) the Mac Address  
Thank you!

Comment: perhaps, the ...input.ToString("X12") is better. but answer is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing it:

```
var address = string.Join(":", BitConverter.GetBytes(addressAsUInt64)
    .Take(6)
    .Reverse()
    .Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))
    );
```